# Как мне воспользоваться двумя массивами одновременно методом ForEach

Tags: javascript, foreach

Первый массив состоит из переменных

```
const item1 = document.querySelector(".item_1");
const item2 = document.querySelector(".item_2");
const item3 = document.querySelector(".item_3");
const item4 = document.querySelector(".item_4");
const item5 = document.querySelector(".item_5");
const item6 = document.querySelector(".item_6");
const item7 = document.querySelector(".item_7");
const item8 = document.querySelector(".item_8");
const item9 = document.querySelector(".item_9");
const item10 = document.querySelector(".item_10");
items = [item1, item2,...,item10]
```

Второй массив состоит из строк, так же количество элементов 10 как и в первом массиве

```
textArr = ['Палка', 'Окно',...,'Шкаф']
```

Как перебрать эти массивы так чтоб получить всем div добавился текст c 2 массива начиная первого элемента текста в первый div(item1), второй элемент текста в второй div(item2) и так далее до 10 div(item10).
Пробовал метод ForEach и получился такой код:

```
items.forEach((elem)) => {
  elem.innerHTML = textArr (Так он выведет всем 10 div все элементы, второго массива)
})
```

Был еще такой вариант:

```
items.forEach((elem)) => {
  let text = ''
  textArr.forEach((i)=>{
     text = i
  })
  elem.innerHTML = text (Так он выведет всем 10 div, последнего элемента второго массива('Шкаф'))
})
```

Результатом чтоб получалось так:

```
<div class='item_1'>Палка</div>
<div class='item_2'>Окно</div>
,...,
<div class='item_10'>Шкаф</div>
```

Comment: добавь пример начальных данных и какой результат ты хочешь получить

Comment: *Так он выведет всем 10 div все элементы, второго массива* - потому что ты не выбираешь конкретный элемент массива.  Если надо чтобы ко всем элементам добавлялся текст первого элемента второго массива надо сделать так: ```elem.innerHTML = textArr[0]```.

Comment: `items.forEach(e => e.innerHTML = textArr.join(' '))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В методе [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) в аргументе `callbackFn` вторым аргументом передаётся `index`. Т.к. количество элементов одинаково и тексты во втором массиве стоят уже в нужном порядке, то можно использовать `index`, чтобы достать нужные элементы у обоих массивов:

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const arr2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];

arr1.forEach((elem, index) => arr1[index] += arr2[index]);

console.log(arr1);
```

Comment: Я обновил информацию, мне нужно получить ко мне моим дивам по одному элементу второго массива, начиная с первого чтоб первый див получил текст 'Палка', второй получил текст 'Окно', и так дальше

Comment: @user552308 Ничего не поменялось. Вам просто теперь нужно вместо `arr1[index] +=` писать `arr1[index].innerHTML +=` и всё

Comment: Почти то что надо) Ты лучший как можно на этом сайте списаться есть чат?

Comment: @user552308 Почему почти? Можете писать тут. При большом количестве сообщений можно будет автоматически создать чат, а так есть чаты [тут](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ru.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Там проблемы со стилями, то уже я сейчас разберусь, просто хотел тебя еще раз поблагодарить, надо еще работать и работать над собой)

Comment: @user552308 Личных чатов тут не бывает, все они публичные. Поблагодарить можно и галочкой и голосом ЗА, нажав на стрелку вверх :)